Почему filters и Command в import подчеркиваются красным(в PyCharm) можете помочь с исправлением или дополнением?
import subprocess
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command

@router.message(Command("restart"))
async def restart(message: types.Message):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "systemctl", "restart", "telegram-bot"])
    await message.answer("Ушел на перезагрузку")


bot.polling(non_stop=True)


У тебя как-то смешение версий. executor есть в aiogram 2, но нет в третей версии. @router.message(Command("restart")) такое написание корутины в aiogram 3. Определись, на какой версии ты пишешь код и проверь, какая версия установлена
